# Outlook IMAP search not returning correct value with BODY search criteria

Tags: outlook, imap

We've been using Chilkat to access emails from outlook accounts and recently we noticed that the search function started failing, I think it started about less than a week ago.

we are connecting to "`office365.outlook.com`" and using Subject and Body as search criteria to get the emails.

Sample search criteria:

```
SUBJECT "Hot Lead (New) - Test Cahestg 92J6cf6n Hot Email" BODY "QA Automation"
```

When it started failing, I did some more investigation and noticed that
SUBJECT `"Hot Lead (New) - Test Cahestg 92J6cf6n Hot Email"` actually works but adding the BODY field causes it to fail.

I did print out the .body of the email object returned and it does have the string "QA Automation" in it so I was wondering why outlook did not return the same email with the search criteria with BODY.

Anyone else have this issue or know of another search field we can use instead of BODY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMAP doesn't specify what the `BODY` search key does, exactly. The server is free to know as little or as much as it wants about body formats.

So if your message uses HTML, to take a common example, and contains the HTML string QA&nbsp;Auto&shy;mation, the server may or may not know that &shy; can be ignored and that &nbsp; is sort of equivalent to a simple space, at least for searching. Similar issues arise for other formats, it's not just HTML. PDF is horrible, even plain text isn't trivial.

As a programming issue this doesn't really have a solution, except maybe issuing OR BODY QA BODY Automation and then doing clientside filtering of the results.

Comment: I actually reached out to chilkat as well and they did mention that the implementation of Search does change depending on the mail server so BODY may not be the best search criteria to use. For now to temporarily resolve our problem we're doing client side filtering before actually showing the results. It's a little inefficient though because you have to get the body of each email that matches a certain subject.

Comment: In my experience, single-word BODY searches are much better than multiword, so you might consider adding "automation" (or both words) to the serverside search and keeping the clientside filtering. There shouldn't be many false positives to download and filter.

Comment: I don't really know what's happening on the outlook side, I tried doing a search with the string: SUBJECT "Hot Lead (New) - Test Cahestg 92J6cf6n Hot Email" BODY "A" and it still did not return any results. The microsoft response to a ticket I raised was very similar to yours. For now I guess the client side filtering is our only way :D

Comment: subject cahestg body butomation? That leaves very little for the server to mishandle, and reduces the number of messages to download and check from perhaps millions to tens or at worst thousands.